# What is the scope of 'SET foreign_key_checks = 0'?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Can't really find any details on this, but is the scope of 'SET foreign_key_checks = 0' the current connection, current session or current transaction?

Comment: I'd say that my question is formulated better than the one referred to above. At least my question ends with a question mark...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a session-based statement.

This is to *temporarily* break the Foreign Key Constraint. It is sometimes necessary to change data in a way that referential integrity needs to be broken during the modification process.

Comment: you answered first, so I'll mark your question as correct.

Answer (score 7):

It is session-based. Full answer and explanation can be found [in this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538716/117259):

> “It is session-based. Do a test to be sure, but that's my understanding of it.”

Comment: Thumbs up for giving the source