# Populating a MySQL database from a DB2 database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, db2, database-performance

I currently have a script for populating a MySQL database from a DB2 server. It works, but it seems to be inserting the rows into MySQL at an extremely slow rate. The server process is executing at ~1% CPU while the script is running, and I'm wondering how I can speed up the insertions.

For security reasons, the administrator of the DB2 database has only provided us with a read-only view of the required tables in the database.

This is my script:

```
<?php

$selectQuery = "SELECT 
                    PK AS COL1,
                    COL2,
                    COL3,
                    COL4,
                    CASE WHEN DATE > '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'
                      THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                      END AS COL5
                FROM table1";

$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `table1` (
                    `fk`,
                    `col2`,
                    `col3`,
                    `col4`,
                    `col5`,
                    `last_updated`
                )
                SELECT :col1, f.`fid`, :col3, :col4, :col5, NOW()
                    FROM f
                    WHERE f.`code` = :col2
                    LIMIT 1
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    `col2` = VALUES(col2),
                    `col3` = VALUES(col3),
                    `col4` = VALUES(col4),
                    `col5` = VALUES(col5),
                    `last_updated` = NOW();";

$paramTypes = array(
    'col1' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
    'col2' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
    'col3' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
    'col4' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
    'col5' => PDO::PARAM_BOOL
);
```

$sync->populate($selectQuery, $insertQuery, $paramTypes);

In the synchronize class (the class that `$sync` is an instance of):

```
<?php

class SyncObject {
    private $db2;
    private $db2_user = '...';
    private $db2_pass = '...';
    private $db2_dbname = '...';
    private $db2_host = 'secure.example.net';
    private $db2_port = ...;

    private $mysql;

    public function __construct() {
        // Establish a DB2 connection
        $this->db2 = db2_pconnect("DATABASE={$this->db2_dbname};HOSTNAME={$this->db2_host};PORT={$this->db2_port};PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID={$this->db2_user};PWD={$this->db2_pass};", '', '');

        // Establish a MySQL connection
        $this->mysql = new PDO('mysql:host=secure-mysql.example.net;port=...;dbname=...', '...', '...', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}

    public function populate($selectQuery, $insertQuery, $paramTypes = array()) {

        $insStmt = $this->mysql->prepare($insertQuery);

        foreach ($paramTypes as $parameterName => $parameterType) {

            $$parameterName = '';

            $insStmt->bindParam(":$parameterName", $$parameterName, $parameterType);
        }

        // Retrieve the data

        $stmt = db2_exec($this->db2, $selectQuery);

        while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            foreach ($row as $fieldName => &$fieldValue) {

                $fieldName = strtolower($fieldName);

                $$fieldName = trim($fieldValue);

                $insStmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, this `populate` method is called six times, once per table. I've only showed one table here. The size of tables range from 20 rows to 21 million rows.

I'm thinking that I can bind uppercase parameters in the query to avoid the `strtolower` function all in the `foreach`, but apart from that minor change are there any suggestions on how to improve the performance of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After briefly investigating how InnoDB was performing the operations, I did the following in order to speed up the insertions:

- Use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) (i.e. turn off autocommit): `$this->mysql->beginTransaction()`. The amount of queries per transaction was limited, although I'm pretty sure MySQL would commit anyways when the InnoDB buffer filled up
- [Disable foreign key checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538636/mysql-set-foreign-key-checks): `SET foreign_key_checks = 0`. The DB2 database had a fairly high integrity, so this was a safe operation.
- Disable unique key checks: `SET unique_checks = 0`. The DB2 database had already enforced unique keys so therefore this was safe.
- [Enable uncommitted reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html): `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Further things to consider were [InnoDB system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html), but these can't really be changed with limited access to the server.

This page may also help, though it lists most of the things listed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Answer (score 2):

Inserting data by row is not going to perform well regardless of what you do. A better approach, in my view, would be to use the DB2 EXPORT command to extract DB2 table data into CSV files, then use MySQL LOAD DATA to, well, load them into the target database. I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I think it should allow you to run external commands using exec().

You will need to install the DB2 Data Server Runtime Client, at a minimum, to be able to run the DB2 command line processor for EXPORT.

Comment: Currently this is not an option for us as we have very little control over the server, however I will keep this suggestion in mind when we migrate to a newer server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try exporting the entire data in to csv file format and then use the load data utilitity to load it into your MySQL database. Load and Export utilities are sure to perform faster than fetching a single row and inserting it one by one.