# Issues with creating a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm having issues with setting up a relation between 2 tables called `Customer` and `Customer_Number`. I have both tables set to `InnoDB` both have indexes, but when I go to create the foreign key, I get a "no index defined" error. Below are some screen shots

Here Is the Customer table.
[image]

Here is the Customer_Number table.

[image]
And here is my error message when trying to create the foreign key.

[image]
And lastly, this is the error I get when trying to create the relationship manually.

[image]
I just can't seem to figure out the issue, and it's driving me nuts!

the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE Customer` is

```
 CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
`Customer_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`First` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Last` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE Customer_Number` is

```
 CREATE TABLE `Customer_Number` (
`Num_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Customer_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Num_ID`),
KEY `Customer_ID` (`Customer_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Updated with requested information

Comment: Hmmm I actually have no problem creating these tables and then adding the FK, or creating them with the FK in the original definition.  This works: `ALTER TABLE Customer_Number ADD FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID);`

Comment: hmmm when I put what you gave me, I get this error `#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`thesnoopz`.`#sql-23d7_8c3428`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-23d7_8c3428_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_ID`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`Customer_ID`)) `

Comment: Ohh, that seems like you might already have a value in some rows in `Customer_Number.Customer_ID` which do not have a corresponding parent row in `Customer.Customer_ID`.  In order to create the FK, any values already there have to be valid row references back to the `Customer` parent table.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Customer_Number WHERE Customer_ID NOT IN (SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customer)` to see if that's the case.

Comment: There are 3 rows in `Customer_Number` and the `Customer_ID` is 0 in all 3 rows. Do these rows need to be empty or deleted to form the FK relation?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to delete them to be able to add the constraint. You can't null them because the column is `NOT NULL`.  It's also possible to temporarily disable FK checks, add the FK constraint, update the rows to point to a matching parent row instead of deleting them, then reenable FK checks; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538636/mysql-set-foreign-key-checks

Comment: That seemed to work. If you want to make it into an answer I will give you the points

Comment: I deleted the rows. The other issue was the fact that I was updating the database via a form, and every time I entered a number, it would save to the `Customer_Number` table, but fill the `Customer_ID` with a 0 value. I deleted those rows and manually enter the values on phpMyAdmin, and it worked. I now need to figure out how to get the `Customer_ID` to work correctly when updating for a web form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `CREATE TABLE` statements as posted are correct and should be able to accept a new `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on `Customer_Number.Customer_ID` since the necessary criteria are met (same data type as referenced column, comparable index or primary key on referenced column).

An `ALTER` statement succeeds in my testing:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer_Number ADD FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer (Customer_ID);
```

Being unfamiliar with how PhpMyAdmin abstracts some RDBMS errors, it is hard to say for sure what exactly has gone wrong in the GUI. But if you run the `ALTER` statement manually and encounter errors about failed foreign key constraints, that's an indication the referencing table already contains values in the column which do not reference a valid row value in the parent table. To uncover those rows so you can address them, execute a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer_Number WHERE Customer_ID NOT IN (SELECT Customer_ID FROM Customer)
```

Once you have found the problematic rows, you can either delete them (if unneeded) or update their values to the value of a valid row value in the referenced table. If the column's definition allowed `NULL` (which yours does not) you could also `UPDATE` them to set them `NULL` then run the `ALTER` statement again.

It is also possible to disable foreign key checks temporarily, add the constraint, update the rows to match valid parent table values, the reenable foreign key checks.

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
alter table Customer_Number add foreign key(customer_ID) references Customer (Customer_ID);
```