# 'SET foreign_key_checks = 1' does not work again

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working with:

- mysql: stable 5.6.22 (bottled)
- MySQLWorkBench 6.2

I have the following sequence

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoicedetail;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoiceheader;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
```

It fails when I work through Java (JDBC) and fails through the MySQLWorkBench too, the error message is about the **FK Child constraints** (I don't have the exact error message), well through Google I did a research and I have found the same valid solution twice.

- [Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19845622)
- [How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501754)

Well I did the following:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoicedetail;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoiceheader;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Again it works, just playing, I tried to execute again

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoicedetail;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoiceheader;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
```

Being sure that `SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;` returns **1**

Well the original error message does not appear again.

Again I did a research on Google and I found the following:

- [mysql SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538716)

Well it says: `It is session-based`

Well, even when:

- mysql server is stopped and restarted again
- workbench re-opened
- Computer re-started

and `SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;` returns **1**

The original error message does not appear again.

Therefore *seems* `'SET foreign_key_checks = 1'` does not work how is expected or an extra configuration/instruction is needed

I want be able to disable and enable that FK security constraint anytime

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem with PHPMyAdmin. After all, the problem was that PHPMyAdmin was adding (by default) the "FOREIGNK_KEY_CHECKS=1".

When I was querying the server with PHPMyAdming the option "Enable foreign key checks" was checked at the end of the page, so none of the "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0" inside my query was actually working.

Please, make sure the solution to your problem is not something so silly like this. ;-)

Comment: It helps! when I do the same in mysql console it works

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It turns out that any rows you modified after “SET foreign_key_checks = 0;” will not be checked in the future, even after “SET foreign_key_checks = 1;”

Found here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks/

Comment: I think you're misreading this: "Notice that setting `foreign_key_checks` to 1 does not trigger any validation of the existing table data. In other words, MySQL will not verify the consistency of the data that was added during the foreign key check disabled." It's not saying they _never_ get checked again; it's saying they're not rechecked immediately upon reenabling the flag.