# How to disable and enable all constraints in table mysql incl. PK FK CHK UNI etc

Tags: mysql

I need to load test data to table and I want to disable every possible constraint, i ve found how to globally turn off the foreign keys, but I need to disable all constraints, PK,FK, CHK, UNIQ etc. Is it possible to do it globally? Of course after that I have to tun all constraints on.

Comment: Why do you think this would be useful??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following to disable constraints:

```
-- disable UNIQ, PK, ...
ALTER TABLE <tablename> DISABLE KEYS;
-- diable FK
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Check for instance [this site](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/set_foreign_key_checks) for more examples. Restore with:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ENABLE KEYS;
```

From the reference:

- [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)
- D[ISABLE KEYS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html): *" Use ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS to tell MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes. ..."*

***p.s.***: from [InnoDB performance tuning tips](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-tuning.html)

```
SET autocommit=0; 
SET unique_checks=0; 
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

Comment: Is it possible to disable all keys globally in schema?

Comment: Disabling is session based as per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538636/does-mysql-foreign-key-checks-affect-the-entire-database

Comment: I issued disable keys command. My schema uses innoDB and returned me warning "Table storage engine for table' doesn't have this option"

Comment: Ok, I see. May be this helps you out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-tuning.html