# Inserting Rows Into a Table Which Participation Constraints Restrict One Another

Tags: mysql, constraints, relationship

I am using mysql. The business requirement is that every `Employee` **must be registered** in a `Department`. However, every `Department` **has to have one** `Manager` to manage the department. As you can see, a `Manager` is an `Employee` itself, so, I only have two tables here, `Employee` and `Department`.

In the `Employee` table, I have a `department` column as  a foreign key that refer to the `Department` table which I gave a `NOT NULL` constraint as it's a total participation. In the `Department` table, I have the `manager` column which I also gave a `NOT NULL` constraint as it's also a total participation.

The initial state of both tables are empty like usual however, now I can't insert data into the `Employee` table as I need to fill the `department` column which is impossible as the `Department` table is still empty. Then, I went to fill the `Department` table and it also doesn't work as the `manager` column cannot be empty and there is no record in the `Employee` table.

Help? :'(

Comment: Is it also possible to disable unique constraint temporarily?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166333/how-to-disable-and-enable-all-constraints-in-table-mysql-incl-pk-fk-chk-uni-etc